# Perl equivalent of Ruby's partition function?

Tags: ruby, arrays, perl

A basic example would be I have an array `['abc','cde','efg']` and want split it into two arrays. One which has the elements containing a `c` and one with the remaining elements.

In ruby I would just say:

```
has_c, no_c = arr.partition { |a| a.include?('c') }
```

Is there a simple perl equivalent?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There's the [`part`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?List::MoreUtils#part) function in [`List::MoreUtils`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?List::MoreUtils):

```
use List::MoreUtils 'part';
my $listref = [ 'abc', 'cde', 'efg' ];

my ($without_c, $with_c) = part { /c/ } @$listref;

print "with c : @$with_c\n";
print "without: @$without_c\n";
```

Outputs:

```
with c : abc cde
without: efg
```

Comment: <pedant>Perl doesn't have list references. What you have there is an array reference.</pedant>

Answer (score 2):

I tried several things with the ternary operator, this seems to work:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

my @a = qw[abc cde efg];
my (@has_c, @no_c);
push @{ \(/c/ ? @has_c : @no_c) }, $_ for @a;

print "c: @has_c\nno: @no_c\n";
```

**Update:** simplified.

Comment: Not very, well, nice to maintain.  How would you write it if you were trying to be more clear?

Comment: @tchrist: Maybe `my @no_c; my @has_c = map { if (/c/) { $_ } else { push @no_c, $_; () } } @a;` ? :-)

Comment: Nice! If you have Perl 5.14 or better, the first arg to `push` can be a reference and `push ((/c/ ? \@has_c : \@no_c), $_) for @a` will work.

Comment: @mob: Yes, I know. Sitting at a 5.10 ATM, though.

Comment: Add newlines: `for (@data) { if (/c/) { push @has_c, $_ } else { push $hasn't_c, $_ }`